# Angular form submit IE9

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, internet-explorer-9

I am building an angular application that requires user to login in a form.
This form is working on both Chrome and Firefox, but not on IE9.

The html form submit:

```
<button  class="btn  btn-theme-bg btn-lg" ng-click="!form.$invalid?login():null"  ng-disabled="loading">Log in&nbsp;&nbsp;<i ng-show="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></button>
```

The controller:

```
$scope.login = function(){
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.doShake = false;
        $scope.invalidCredentials = false;
        userRestService.login($scope.user).$promise.then(function(client){
            console.log('login ok');
            sharedDataService.setCurrentClient(client);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('userLoggedIn');
            $state.go('root.dashboard.list');

        }).catch(function(){
            $scope.attemptCount = $scope.attemptCount+1;
            if($scope.attemptCount>1){$scope.doShake = true;};
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.user.password = '';
            $scope.passwordError = false;
            $scope.invalidCredentials = true;
        });
    };
```

On IE9, after submit, the API is targeted via HTTP POST with the right parameters and works as expected, and after returning that the user is ok, the routing is wrong and the login and the password appear in clear in the URL before the #:

http://localhost:3000/?email=test@test.com&password=test#/home

Any idea what might cause this error in IE9 only?

Comment: This is a wrong method. You should never pass user's password in querystring. Make sure your end point (API) accepts only post method.

Comment: userRestService.login($scope.user) is a POST method, from my resource:

login: {method: 'POST', params:{action:'login'}, cache: false, isArray: false},

Comment: Can we see the login service?

Comment: Client side: 
login: {method: 'POST', params:{action:'login'}, cache: false, isArray: false},

Server side (expressjs):
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'),function(req, res){
    return res.json({type: true, data: req.user});
});